# Angular2 RC1 Parent to Child data through Input Binding

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

So I'm having trouble with input binding now that I've upgraded to RC1.  Here's what I have for the view:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="limitControl" class="form-control" 
                [(ngModel)]="limit" (change)="limitChanged($event)">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="0">All</option>
        </select>
        <label for="limitControl"> {{recordType}} per page</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the view for the following component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'limiter',
    templateUrl: 'frontend/common/limiter/view.html',
    styleUrls: ['frontend/common/limiter/style.css']
})

export class LimiterComponent {
    limit: number = 10;

    @Input() recordType: string;
    @Output() limitChangedEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();

    limitChanged($event) {
        this.limitChangedEvent.emit($event.currentTarget.value);
    }
}
```

And finally, this is being called by it's parent:

```
<limiter (limitChangedEvent)="limitChanged($event)" 
         [recordType]="Campaigns"></limiter>
```

recordType doesn't seem to be passed into the child component.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you missing a closing `</form>` tag in your view.html?

Comment: It wasn't indented and swallowed by SO

Comment: I can't see a bug. Maybe the issue is how `Campaigns` is set.

Comment: What does the parent component look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try it in this way :

```
export class LimiterComponent {
        limit: number = 10;

        @Input('record-type') recordType: string;
        @Output() limitChangedEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();

        limitChanged($event) {
            this.limitChangedEvent.emit($event.currentTarget.value);
        }
    }
```

Parent Component:

```
<limiter (limitChangedEvent)="limitChanged($event)" 
         record-type="Campaigns"></limiter>
```

Comment: You were correct!! except in the parent component, you drop the brackets.  So:

`<limiter (limitChangedEvent)="limitChanged($event)" 
         record-type="Campaigns"></limiter>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to the naming convention. Look at the `Input` documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html), notice that you're using *camelCasing* for your **DOM** binding -- whereas the documentation shows the usage of a hyphen instead?

**Instead of this**

```
<limiter (limitChangedEvent)="limitChanged($event)" 
         [recordType]="Campaigns"></limiter>
```

**Try this**

```
<limiter (limitChangedEvent)="limitChanged($event)" 
         record-type="Campaigns"></limiter>
```

Comment: Angular doesn't nees that.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/dom/util.ts

Comment: Rhey might use it "somewhere" but templates are case sensitive since quite some time and `recordType` is a valid input and output name in class and template.